# Prove that series $ \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n $ and $ \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^n $ have the same radius of convergence.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, power-series

I want to prove that these two power series
$$
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n
$$
and
$$
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^n
$$
have the same radius of convergence.

---

What I've done so far is:

1. I replace $(x-x_0)$ with $y$ to make calculations easier.
2. In order to find the radius I use the Cauchy's criterion (Root test):
   1:
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_ny^n} < 1\\
   y\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} < 1\ \ \ (*)\\
   $$
   2:
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[n]{(n+1)a_{n+1}y^n}) < 1\\
   y\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[n]{n+1})\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[n]{a_{n+1}}) < 1\\
   y\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[n]{a_{n+1}}) < 1 \ \ \ (**)
   $$
3. I haven't found the radius, but if I take the limit of $(*)$ and $(**)$ as $n \to \infty$ then $(*)$ and $(**)$ should be equal.

---

Is my reasoning correct? Can we actually get a formula for the radius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can apply the formula of the radius of convergence. Your solution is essentially correct. Here is a more direct way to present it.

Given the series 
$$
S_1(x)= \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n
$$
its radius of convergence $\rho_1$ is 
$$\frac{1}{\rho_1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert a_n  \vert}$$ 
Given the series 
$$
S_2(x)= \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^n
$$
then, its radius of convergence $\rho_2$ is
$$\frac{1}{\rho_2} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{(n+1)\vert a_{n+1}  \vert}$$
Now, since we know $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$, we have 
$$\frac{1}{\rho_2} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{(n+1)\vert a_{n+1}  \vert}=(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1})\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert a_{n+1}  \vert}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert a_n  \vert}=\frac{1}{\rho_1}$$
So we have $\rho_1=\rho_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the last question on whether or not one can get a formula, the [Cauchy--Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) says that the radius of convergence $R$ of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \lvert a_n \rvert^{1/n},$$
where the possibilities $0$ and $\infty$ are treated in the natural way.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems to be reasonable, however I believe that there is an easier way to prove the statement.

---

**Note** that the second series is, actually, a derivative of the first. 
Indeed, denote 
$F(x) = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n$ and 
$G(x) = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1) a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^n$. 
Take derivative of $F$:

$$
F'(x) = \left(\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n\right)' = 
\left(a_0 + \sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}a_n(x-x_0)^n\right)' = 
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}na_n (x-x_0)^{n-1}
$$
Let us shift summation index by $-1$ by making change of variables $m = n-1$. 
Then we get 
$$
F'(x) =  \sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}na_n (x-x_0)^{n-1}
= \sum^{+\infty}_{m=0}(m+1)a_{m+1} (x-x_0)^{m}
$$
Without Loss of generality, we can re-lable $m$ back to $n$, thus getting 
$$
F'(x) = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)a_{n+1} (x-x_0)^{n} = G(x)
$$

As we know, differentiation and integration [does not change radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration) of power series.

Thus,  the radius of convergence of $F$ and $G$ is the same.

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: OP is most likely attempting to prove that a power series and its formal derivative have the same radius of  convergence...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM. Actually, I just wanted to prove that these two power series have the same radius of convergence. I had no idea, that one is a derivative of another. Vlad's solution is really interesting

Comment: @moonnoon I agree this theorem is powerful but you'll have to prove it one way or another